# How can I remove a class from an element with a matching attribute/value?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I remove the class `header` from all `<th>` elements with the attribute `nofilter="True"`?

```
<th class="header" nofilter="True" scope="col" align="left">City</th>
```

The result should be:

```
<th nofilter="True" scope="col" align="left">City</th>
```

Comment: You know, api.jquery.com would probably have provided this answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("th[nofilter='True']").removeClass("header");
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comments noted, I rushed my answer, the correct statement would be

```
$("th[nofilter='True']").removeClass("header");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Removeclass

Comment: Actually he wants to only affect the ones with that "nofilter" attribute, so it'd be `$('th[nofilter=True]').removeClass('header')`

Comment: This would remove all classes. But only th with nofilter="True" should be removed

Comment: Yepp, now I see it, didn't got that the first time, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("th[nofilter='True']").removeClass("header");
```

this should work for nofilter="True" only